# How do i get the current session of the user inside a system process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32-process

I have a DLL which is hosted inside a process which runs under Administrator context. The DLL recieves callbacks based on logged in user actions. GetUserName() returns the Admin username instead of the logged in user who is responsible for the callback by his actions. Im trying to impersonate the logged in user to get exact user name but i haven't succeded. I have tried using **WTSEnumerateSessions()** to enumerate sessions. All it does is return users that are Active. But i have no way to tell who the current user is from the enumerated sessions.

Enumeration looks like below under Windows Servers. Is there a way i can tell who the current user is from the Active Users?

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>rdp-tcp#5         User1                     3  Active
 console           Administrator             4  Active
 rdp-tcp#8         User2                     5  Active
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

I have tried using **WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()**. But it always returns the session ID of the user logged in physically. But never the session ID's of users logged in through RDP.

If any of you have solved this kind of issue, please help me out.

Comment: What interprocessing tools are you using for the other process to pass the callback? COM/DCOM, NET, other?

Comment: You keep repeating the phrase *"the logged in user"*, but have already discovered, that more than one user can be logged into any given system at any given time. Maybe you need to solve that issue first.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta COM/DCOM is used for interprocess and the callback is given by one of the OS feature which doesn't give information about the user.

Comment: @llnspectable Parallel login is a feature of Windows Server OS'es. Multiple users can login at the same time

Comment: Remote Desktop Services were a Windows Server feature back when they were called *"Terminal Services"*. Totally besides the point: There is not such thing as *"**the** logged in user"*. If you keep insisting, that there were, you're not going to solve this issue. Which user account requested your service needs to be communicated to your service. As you discovered, you cannot guess it.

Comment: You can get the token for the session user via [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken). This requires SeTcbPrivilege, which as an admin user you can get by impersonating SYSTEM.

Comment: @Eryk Sun problem is I don't know which user to query for. I get all the sessions listed but need a way to detect current active user

Comment: @Eryk Sun If there are 3 users logged in and you are one of the non-admin user under whose session the callback is recieved, you are the "Current Active User". The process runs as Admin and when you are in an user session who is non-admin, doing WTSQueryUserToken(WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, &hToken) in the callback will give the token of Admin. I need a way to get the non-admin user at that point.

Comment: @ErykSun From your previous comment it seems like from Session 0 it's impossible. Is that correct? I'm out of all options and dont see a way.

Comment: So your process is in the non-interactive session 0 running as a service? `WTSQueryUserToken` will work fine if you know the session ID to query. There is no "current active user" as far as that goes. Threads executing in all sessions are concurrent. I see you're working with some concept of a current user in terms of callbacks based on user actions that your process is receiving. If a request comes from a client via COM: `CoImpersonateClient`.

Comment: @user3145865 Have you tried ProcessIdToSessionId?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-processidtosessionid

Comment: @kvr It doesn't work. Because process is running in Session0 and the the call return 0

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks for all the help. Unfortunately i couldn't get it working. I ended up using WTSEnumSessions and chose the first active user from the list. Which will work for non server OS'es as there will be only one active session anytime. For server versions, its gonna be a constraint.